# Web Push notification Received unexpected response code

Tags: c#, multithreading, push-notification, web-push, web-notifications

```
webPushClient.SendNotification(subscriptionkey, JsonData, vapidDetails);
```

When i am trying to push web notification to browser then i am getting this below exception.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
 ---> WebPush.WebPushException: Received unexpected response code 
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) 
   at WebPush.WebPushClient.<SendNotificationAsync>d__15.MoveNext()   
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at WebPush.WebPushClient.SendNotification(PushSubscription subscription, String payload, VapidDetails vapidDetails) 
   at ServerMonitor.Program.Main(String[] args)
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) WebPush.WebPushException: Received unexpected response code 
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) 
   at WebPush.WebPushClient.<SendNotificationAsync>d__15.MoveNext()<---
```

but its creating issue production environment,after 48 hours it starts pushing the notification,unable to get where it went after 48 hours it starts working,wrong for the initial 48 hrs

Comment: `unexpected response code`... You need at least to find that HTTP status code. Otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: I am getting HTTP status code 400

Comment: I have seen Google returning `400` also for authentication errors (i.e. wrong VAPID configuration). You should also check the status name returned together with `400` because can be something more specific than `Bad Request`.

Comment: maybe Gone = 410 //  Equivalent to HTTP status 410. System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Gone indicates that the requested resource is no longer available.